# Estimation: what does it mean that the observable cancel from my equations?

Tags: statistics, systems-of-equations, interpolation, estimation

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$I have a problem which remind me of inconsistent system of equations from linear algebra, but I cannot see what the problem is. There are $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ random variables (the data). I want to estimate some observable $A$ which is a function of $n$ unknown quantities which I hope to estimate from the data. Assume these quantities are called $\theta_1,\theta_2,\dots,\theta_n$:
$$
A = f(\theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots, \theta_n )
$$
I have obtained some estimators $\hat \theta_i$ such that the expectation $\E \hat \theta_i (A,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) = \theta_i$ depend on $A$ and all observations for all $i$. The problem is that when I plug these into the equation for $A$ and I want to solve for $A$, the observable $A$ cancels. I.e. there is some function $g$ that does not depend on $A$ but 
\begin{align}
A & = f(\E \hat \theta_1 (A,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n), \ldots, \E \hat \theta_n (A,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) ) \\
& = g(\E\hat\theta_1(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n), \ldots, \E\hat\theta_n(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) ) + A
\end{align}
That is a problem because it implies that 
$$
0 = g(\E\hat\theta_1(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n), \ldots, \E\hat\theta_n(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) ),
$$
and instead of solving for $A$, $A$ is eliminated from the equations altogether! What is going on?

EDIT:
To clarify what I am asking. Most of the time we are able to solve for $A$ in sets of equations. But every once in a while it doesn't work and $A$ cancels (like in my case). What is the name of sets of equations which has this property? How can one identify that a set of nonlinear equations cannot be solved for $A$? I would like more intimate understanding of the mechanisms which imply we cannot solve for $A$.

Comment: "a statistic" is not a proper term for what $A$ is. A _statistic_ is an observable random variable -- a known function of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You have a function $(X_1,\ldots,X_n) \mapsto \widehat{\theta\,}_i (A, X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n).$ A problem is that the value of this function appears to depend not just on the observable data $X_1, \ldots, X_n,$ but also on $A.$ But $A$ is not observable. An estimator must be observable.

Comment: Added to the thread: Most of the time we are able to solve for $A$ in sets of equations. But every once in a while it doesn't work. What is the name of sets of equations which has this property? How can one identify that a set of nonlinear equations cannot be solved for $A$? I would like more intimate understanding of the mechanisms which implies that we cannot solve for $A$.

Comment: @MariusJonsson : Maybe more could be said if you tell us exactly what the equations are.

Comment: I think this is most easily kept abstract. But we can try. Suppose $n = 2^d$, for some natural number $d$ and $(n-1)A = \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} 2^i \theta_i$. $\hat A$ would be an unbiased if $A = E \hat A$. This happens if we find some $\hat \theta_i$ such that $E \hat \theta_i = \theta_i$. I've found some statistic $\hat c_i$ such that $E \hat c_i = \theta_i - A$. Hence letting $\hat \theta_i = \hat c_i + A$, then $A(n-1) = E A(n-1) = \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} 2^i E \hat \theta_i = \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} 2^i (E\hat c_i + A) = (2^d - 1)A + \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} 2^i E\hat c_i = (n - 1)A + \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} 2^i E\hat c_i$

Comment: There are a couple of hats missing hats $\hat \cdot$ above the $A$'s in the above comment, but I ran out of characters.

Comment: Here's a somewhat more legible format: $$\begin{align} A(n-1) & = \operatorname{E} A(n-1) = \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} 2^i \operatorname{E} \hat \theta_i = \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} 2^i (\operatorname{E} \hat c_i + A) \\ & = (2^d - 1)A + \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} 2^i \operatorname{E} \hat c_i = (n - 1)A + \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} 2^i \operatorname{E} \hat c_i \end{align}$$